# NHibernate Performance and Scalability

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, webforms

I have a web forms site that use NHibernate to connect to a MSSQL database.

I use the following class to create the SessionFactory and get the current session to use:

```
internal static class SessionManager
{
    static readonly Configuration Configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
    internal readonly static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

    internal static ISession CurrentSession { get { if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(SessionFactory))CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession()); return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); } }
}
```

And that is an example of how I use the previous one:

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity>
{

    protected internal ISession Session { get { return SessionManager.CurrentSession; } }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> AllItems { get { return Session.Query<TEntity>(); } }

}
```

Everything works fine, although I believe I'm doing something really bad in terms of performance and scalability, but I can't see what.

Can anyone point me out what is and/or suggest a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are other ways to organize it, that I find better (personal preference). But there's nothing wrong with your solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue in your code is that, when you put the Session object as a static field in a static class, you will have only one session for the whole process, what can bring you problems, like "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session", for example.

What you could do is create another static method to allow you to close the session, but you would have to control when to close it (in a web environment, it could be in the end of every Request), or you could use some dependency injection framework like **NInject** or **Castle Windsor** to control the lifetime of the Session object.

Take a look at this:
[(Yet another) nHibernate sessionmanager for ASP.NET (MVC)](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2011/09/26/yet-another-nhibernate-sessionmanager-for-asp-net-mvc/)
[Effective NHibernate Session management for web apps](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2011/03/02/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.html)